# Use of aubio.note() in python?

Tags: python, aubio

I'm trying to use aubio to find the notes in a recording. Whenever I call aubio.notes with `aubio.notes(filename)`, the python shell crashes (windows dialogue: pythonw.exe has stopped working). The only "documentation" I found are [these](https://aubio.org/manpages/latest/aubionotes.1.html) [pages](https://aubio.org/aubionotes.html) for the command line commands. I figured out the first argument is a string (presumably file name?). Based on the uses of `aubio.pitch` and `aubio.tempo` and `aubio.source`, `note` is a class, and methods are used on an instance of this class. Does anyone know how to use this?

It does work when called as `n = aubio.note()`, but I've no clue where to go from there

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/aubio/aubio/issues/60

See also [this demo](https://github.com/aubio/aubio/blob/master/python/demos/demo_notes.py)

Please open a new bug report whenever you see a such crash.